# Background img width controlled by text inside. Height stays static

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a div with the background img of a bubble that have the count of comments on a post inside it. I want the width to be controlled by the text inside while the height of the div should stay static so I can keep the text inside centered verticaly.

What I have now is the code under here. It looks ok when the value inside is a 3 digit number, but if I change it to a 2 digit number or anything other then a 3 digit number the bubble moves verticaly and horizontaly so the text is not centered anymore.

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  min-width: 100%;
  align-items: baseline;
}
#comment_text {
  display: flex;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#comment_img {
  display: flex;
  background: url('https://rajohan.no/img/icons/picons_basic_1/SVG/basic1-021_chat_comment_bubble.svg'); 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  padding: 21px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
#comment_count {
  display: flex;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="comment_text">
    COMMENTS
  </div>
  <div id="comment_img">
    <div id="comment_count">
      160
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added some code in your `#comment_count`.

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  min-width: 100%;
  align-items: baseline;
}
#comment_text {
  display: flex;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#comment_img {
  display: flex;
  background: url('https://rajohan.no/img/icons/picons_basic_1/SVG/basic1-021_chat_comment_bubble.svg'); 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  padding: 21px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
#comment_count {
  display: flex;
  font-weight: bold;
  min-height: 20px;
  min-width: 25px;
 justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="comment_text">
    COMMENTS
  </div>
  <div id="comment_img">
    <div id="comment_count">
      160
    </div>
  </div>
</div>           

<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="comment_text">
    COMMENTS
  </div>
  <div id="comment_img">
    <div id="comment_count">
      22
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! what you added + sideroxylon answer made it work perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `background-position:center` - this centers the background image horizontally as the element changes width.  I think that's what you're trying to achieve.

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  min-width: 100%;
  align-items: baseline;
}

#comment_text {
  display: flex;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.comment_img {
  display: flex;
  background: url('https://rajohan.no/img/icons/picons_basic_1/SVG/basic1-021_chat_comment_bubble.svg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  padding: 21px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.comment_count {
  display: flex;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="comment_text">
    COMMENTS
  </div>
  <div class="comment_img">
    <div class="comment_count">
      16
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="comment_img">
    <div class="comment_count">
      160
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```